# How to do join query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

Business Model

```
   public function groupTag()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo('GroupTag');
   }
```

Group Tag Model

```
    public function tag()
    {
        return $this-    >belongsToMany('Tag','group_tag_tags','group_tag_id','tag_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function business()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Business');
    }
```

Tag Model

```
   public function groupTag()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group','group_tag_tags','group_tag_id','tag_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Now how do i run this query into a laravel project

`SELECT * FROM`businesses` as b, 
group_tags as gt,
group_tag_tags as gtt,
tags as t
where b.group_tag_id = gt.id and gt.id = gtt.group_tag_id and gtt.tag_id = t.id and t.id = 36 or b.name like '%a%' and b.city_id = 5 group by b.id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('businesses')
        ->join('group_tags','group_tags.id','=','businesses.group_tag_id')
        ->join('group_tag_tags','group_tag_tags.group_tag_id','=','group_tags.id')
        ->join('tags','tags.id','=','group_tag_tags.tag_id')
        ->where('tags.id',"=",36)
        ->where('b.name',"LIKE",'%a%')
        ->where('b.city_id',"=",5)
        ->select('businesses.id','businesses.name','businesses.description','businesses.image')
        ->groupBy('businesses.id')
```